# Javascrpt: send a fetch request within a fetch request

Tags: javascript, html

I have a for DRF api which I use as a back end and use fetch() to post and get data by using GET on /api/u/:username/Posts

After i get a list of posts, i use a for loop to go through.

The posts have a "liked" attr which is retrieved by using GET on /api/:username/posts//Liked which returns either true or false.

How can I access "liked" within the for loop?

Comment: By storing it in a variable. Then you can access it in a for loop

Comment: You will have to call API to fetch likes for every post in loop (since it is async code, you might have to use Promise.all or similar async API). I am not sure if this is the best way of handling this use-case as you will end up making lot of API calls. Better approach would be to update `/api/u/:username/Posts` API to return `liked` attribute as well.